# Have different background colour for each div in one page

Tags: html, css

My site has a fixed nav bar and I added in a carousel so I used position: absolute so I can display the width 100% of the resolution screen size.

I'm trying to have different background colours for different information on my website. Like this website
http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB046281S

I know how to make it a different background colour but what I'm having problem is when I resize the windows my text gets overlapped here's an example:

[image]

Comment: Please provide executable example (i.e. use [codepen](http://codepen.io/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/))

Answer (score 0):

You can create div with different background color like this

HTML

```
<div id="sec-one">
</div>
<div id="sec-two">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#sec-one {
  background-color: red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}
#sec-one {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}
```